# .Net Standard Library With Nuget Packages Used in .Net Framework Project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-standard, .net-4.8

I'm currently working with two projects: a .NET Standard 2.0 class library and a .NET Framework 4.6.2 console application. In my .NET Standard library, I'm using the System.Diagnostics.EventLog library.

I wrote a method in .NET Standard project:

```cs
public static void LogTest()
{
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, "Application");
}
```

However, when I attempt to call the LogTest method from the .NET Framework console application, I encounter an error stating `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

I was under the impression that the .NET Framework project should automatically copy these dependencies from the .NET Standard library, but it doesn't. So I added
`<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>`
line to NET Standard 2.0 class library csproj, it copies the file to build directory of Net Standard project, but still .NET Framework does not have System.Diagnostics.EventLog dll in build directory, so I made their build directory the same, but now I am getting:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'EventLog access is not supported on this platform.'
```

exception. When I investigated, I saw that the System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll is for .Net Standard 2.0 in build directory. I copied System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll for .NET Framework 4.6.2 from Nuget directory (C:\Users\XXX.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.eventlog\8.0.0).

I could not find a document for this problem, and asked Github Copilot, and it said add the nuget package also to the NET Framework project, and it seems it solved the problem, but **this is not a good solution**, because I have to know every nuget package references in the other projects.

I uploaded an example project here: https://github.com/sahin52/NetStandardInNetFrameworkProjExcample you can build and see the same problems, and ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj has a line with CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies, which is commented out currently, you can test it by removing comment tags also.

How can I solve this problem in a nice way? Thanks in advance.

Edit: **This is not only related to this package**, I also got the same error for ModifyRegistry:  `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Registry is not supported on this platform.`.

Comment: The problem is trying to use a Windows feature in a cross-platform library. There's no Windows Event Log in Linux or Mac, which means there can't be a dependency to it in a .NET Standard library. Instead of using your own logging code, it would be a **lot** better to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` and have your projects use `ILogger`, with the actual logger provider supplied by the executable project. You can configure multiple logging targets, including files, the console, event log, Elastic etc. Most NuGet packages work with ILogger by now.

Comment: The example project is small, but the project I need to update is not a simple one and I might have to edit 10s of projects. Also currently this project will still only be used in Windows.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact .NET Standard is cross-platform. Why switch to .NET Standard if you want to use Windows-specific features anyway?

Comment: One could say that hard-coding calls to the Event Log inside `LogTest` is a bad design too. A better design would do what all logging libraries do - offer an interface that clients can use for logging, and provide the actual log target implementations separately. Your .NET Standard implementation only needs to know about the logging interface. That's how log4net, NLog, Common.Logging, Serilog and now Microsoft.Extensions.Logging work

Comment: Becuase eventually we need to convert to .Net Core, currently we are using .Net Framework, but there is a total of ~50 projects, so we are trying to firstly convert to Net Standard and then to Net Core to minimize problems

Comment: Then use ILogger. All NuGet packages use this interface. That means all the libraries you use expect this to exist. It doesn't matter how many projects there are. You can't use Windows features in .NET Standard

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, **.Net Standard build of this dll throws this error, but .net Framework version of the same dll does not throw error**. So you need to install the same package to .Net Framework library(Even though it is not used in the project).

When  you build .Net Framework project, it will copy the .Net Framework version of the same dll. This way you may use this dll instead of .Net Standard version of it. But be sure to build .Net Framework project every time, because nuget packages are copied automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead you can use the .NET Platform Extensions.  This allows you to use Windows-specific libraries in a .NET Core project without having to go through .NET Standard.

First you need the Windows Compatibility Pack.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility --version 8.0.0
```

Then you can install the EventLog library.

```
dotnet add package System.Diagnostics.EventLog --version 8.0.0
```

Comment: They are on .NET Framework, not .NET Core....

Comment: OP says, "Becuase eventually we need to convert to .Net Core, currently we are using .Net Framework"  The whole reason they were considering using .NET Standard is because of this conversion, otherwise you could have just done this natively in .NET Framework.

Comment: That still does not copy the packages to build directory, the main problem here is to find the related nuget package in the build directory of Net Framework project.